# Git Personal Access Token not being accepted for git clone in linux

Tags: github, command

I'm new to development and trying to improve my git skills.  I've followed git's directions to create a PAT.  Now I'm trying to use it in lieu of my password while trying to clone a repository, but I continue to get the "Support for password authentication...." error message.  Any thoughts on what I may be doing wrong here?

[image of error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tMXu0.png)

Comment: Those aren't *Git's* directions, those are Git*Hub*'s. I fixed your tag here, but I'm not sure that anyone can help much with the question as it is.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.